# Network address inaccessible if ran by the Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, user-accounts, windows-networking, network-shares

I have a C# program that does this:

```
Directory.Exists(@"\\PcName\SomeDir");
```

and prints whether that path is accessible (exists) or not.

This is the problem: I run this app via the `Task Scheduler` right after log-in (auto-log-in user), using the "On Login" trigger, and it returns `false`, although that path ***IS*** accessible! (I manage to open that path using the explorer.exe few seconds before my app starts). It is marked to:

```
Run with highest privileges
```

If I run it manually it runs OK, even when I right click the task and select "Run" via the `Task Scheduler`!

- If I ***deselect*** "Run with highest privileges", there is no problem, but it must be ran with highest privileges (accesses registry and whole lot other stuff)
- It runs under same user if I run it manually or automatically by the task scheduler - I made sure using Process Explorer
- It happens on certain machines (Win8x64, admin-privileges-user with no password, auto-log-in, workgroup machines, not domain), but not on anothers (same: Win8x64, admin-privileges-user with no password, auto-log-in, workgroup machines, not domain).
- Even if I insert `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));` or enter 1-min delay in the task (in the Task Scheduler) it still says this path does not exist

Comment: You can run Process Monitor or Wireshark while the task is running, maybe you'll see something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to "impersonate", although I’m not really sure why: if I use the scheduler without restarting, it accesses the remote share – exactly the same settings, one to one. Only after restart it fails to access the share (and a moment later, again – same settings, it is able to access).

The only difference in running it immediately after restart is that the app-process’s parent is `services.exe` and not `explorer.exe` as usual. My guess is that it has to log in immediately after the restart, so it must use `services.exe` (`explorer.exe` is not supposed to exist at that stage, if I'm not mistaken).

Below is the solution in `C#`, roughly, to whom it may concern:

```
// LogonUser is a "P/Invoked" API:
// http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LogonUser.html
// this solution works only with the LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS as the 4th parameter:
using (var h = LogonUser(username, domain, password, 
    LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 
    LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT))
{
    using (var winImperson8Ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(h.DangerousGetHandle())) {
        return Directory.Exists(path); // now works fine...    
    }
}
```